# How to organize folders?

Tags: android

How can I organize folders in Android Studio? Can I move all layout folders to one folder named "layout" for example?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No… but also yes.

You cannot change the organizational structure of the resource folders because that structure is how the Android framework determines which resources to load based on a given device configuration.

But you can change how the resources *appear* within Android Studio. Select the project view menu in the top-left corner of the Project Tool Window (shown below).

[image]

Then select `Android`. This will group all resources of the same type in a single resource folder, regardless of the resource qualifiers.

[image]

P.S. You will need to wait for any indexing to finish to see the resources grouped in this way; otherwise it will still show the resources in the default `Project` view style.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose Android view in Project tab:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot rearrange folders. But it seems you are using "Project Files" view type of that tree. Switch to "Android" to have some folders shown grouped.